# Need help making a div appear on the bottom of the screen while the rest of the divs scroll

Tags: html, css

It's hard to describe my specific problem without just showing you the HTML code.

The HTML source can be seen easily from clicking "View Source" while seeing the page http://techdot.us/projects/jeopardy/view.php. The CSS is located [here](http://techdot.us/projects/jeopardy/style/gameStyle.css).

My main goal is to have the main content table rows/columns appear on the majority of the screen (everything except 69px, to be exact).

So, the bottom 69px contains an informational panel that is supposed to stay on the bottom of the screen, even when the user scrolls down the page.  Scrolling is supposed to, in theory, trigger the majority of the content to go down the page normally, except the bottom bar which stays static.

I have achieved this effect on the website. However, there is a big problem. On smaller screens (as you can simulate by resizing the window), some of the main table gets cut off. It seems that my CSS solution is a botch, and, in effect, does not accomplish my main goal.  The bottom bar should not cut off part of the table from the main content div (gameTable), but the main content div should display all of its content in a scrollable fashion.

My CSS at the moment works as long as the viewer's screen is a certain pixel height. This is definitely not permanent.

Thank you SO much for the help. I really appreciate it and totally understand that I'm being a total pain by just throwing down tons of CSS and HTML code to edit.

Comment: Hahaha what is the meaning of life? 42. XD

Comment: Which browser are you using? For me it works fine on small windows.

Comment: Internet explorer: The bottom bar doesn't even stay put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following css to your container div.

```
padding-bottom:69px;/* height of bottom bin*/
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! The only problem is that Internet Explorer does not like a) the font on the main page, and b) the whole container div system I'm using... hmmm

Comment: @user1896600 IE doesn't like position fixed, try using absolute and relative positions for IE to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you don't like that on a small screen the score bar on the bottom covers up some of the table when you scroll down to the maximum? Your question was very hard to interpret.

The simplest fix would be to simple put in:

```
<div style="height:69px"></div>
```

After your gameTable but before your scores, this means there will always be a gap of 69 extra pixels at the bottom of the screen, so the score bar won't cover anything.

Comment: Sorry that the question was vague. What I meant to ask was that I wanted to know the correct and best way to implement the two-div layout in which the top div can be as long as it needs to be, and can scroll up/down while the bottom div stays put. The issue with mine currently is that a black bar appears at the bottom when you scroll down, and is different heights depending on how big the screen you view it from is.

Comment: One more quick question... why is there a 30px space before my main container div (the main part which looks like a piece of paper, with all of the content on it)? I set the div's margin-top to 0...